# php displaying data from db isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am currently trying to echo data from my mysql database but im having no luck, nothing is being displayed on the page, no data or no error so i was wondering what ive done wrong, thanks

```
 <?php 
    Include('connect.php');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC");

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query));

            $id = $rows ['id'];
            $date = $rows ['date'];
            $title = $rows ['title'];
            $content = $rows ['content'];

            echo "$title <br> $content <br> $date";

    ?>
```

edit: the connect.php works as im using it for a contact form, just using a different table

Comment: Does the query work by itself? Any errors reported?

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop has two problems:

1. You terminate it with a semi-colon ending the loop
2. Your code needs to be contained within curly braces

Fix:

```
<?php 
    Include('connect.php');

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC");

        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $id = $rows ['id'];
            $date = $rows ['date'];
            $title = $rows ['title'];
            $content = $rows ['content'];

            echo "$title <br> $content <br> $date";
         }
    ?>
```

FYI, the `mysql` API is obsolete. You shouldn't be writing new code with it. You should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: To add to this answer, omitting braces only works for a single statement.  For example, if you only had `$id = $rows['id'];` in the while.

Comment: @Devon Correct. I thought about adding that here but decided against it as it is out of scope for this question.